# Nestjs - Cannot find module dist\main

Tags: typescript, nestjs

I'm using nestjs. I have a front application so I've decided to create a "common" folder for both front and back:

```
    project  
    │
    └───common
    │   │
    │   └───dtos
    │       │   dto-a.ts
    │       │   dto-b.ts
    │   
    └───api  (==> nestjs)
    │   │
    │   └───src
    │
    └───front
        │
        └───src
```

In both front and back, I have added this to tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      "@common/*": ["../common/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

So I can use my models like this:

```js
import { DtoA} from "@common/dtos";
```

However, since I made the change, the compilation is creating two folder under the `dist` folder:

```
    dist
    │
    └───common
    │   
    └───api
```

Nestjs tries to find something into `dist/main`, and fails:

> Error: Cannot find module 'path\to\project\api\dist\main'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

How can I tell nestjs to look into `dist/api/main`, or how can I bundle the common folder inside the api build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It needed to add to the nest-cli the "entryFile" key.
example: "entryFile": "./apps/users/src/main.js",

Comment: it works! I set it to `api/src/main.js`